# Can we use class as view in django?

Tags: python, django

### view.py

```
class myapp():

   def index(self):
      return redirect(someusrl)

   def productview(self):
      return redirect(someusrl)
```

### urls.py

path('', myapp.index, name="home"),

path('product', myapp.productview, name="Product_page")

like this way

thanks in advance :)

Comment: why yo create the function views inside that class? did you tried with **Class-Based Views**? https://ccbv.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are creating functions inside that class? Instead of this you should use django class-based views.

Here is the documentation :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/